# How do we programmatically delete SendGrid account information for GDPR related requests?

Tags: twilio, sendgrid, twilio-api, sendgrid-api-v3

We use SendGrid to deliver our emails to our customers. We are implementing a light-weight internal infrastructure to handle GDPR requests from our customers. We would like to know how to forward relevant requests to Sendgrid, as our downstream dependency, to ensure complete deletion of our user information. I noticed from the below link that SendGrid is covered by Twilio's Data Protection Addendum, https://sendgrid.com/resource/general-data-protection-regulation-2/. But I could not find any definitive documentation around API support or actual deletion process with respect to GDPR at Twilio.

If someone could point me to any relevant document or API, it would be helpful.

Thanks,
Dheeban

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid there is no API to programmatically delete SendGrid information.

The process to get user data deleted under GDPR is as follows:

> Because we retain email message activity for only a short time, most
> deletion requests are handled through our automatic timeout process;
> however, if you require an earlier deletion, please reach out to us
> directly at datasubjectrequests@sendgrid.com. Please include the
> following information:
>
> - Customer Account ID (or subaccount if applicable)
> - Recipient email address to be deleted
>
> To ensure correct and timely processing of your request, please
> include this information in CSV (comma-separated value) format, or in
> a spreadsheet with two delineated columns. If you are requesting
> removal of more than one account, please send multiple requests for
> deletion in a single spreadsheet or CSV file. Your deletion request
> will be completed within 7 days.
>
> Submissions in an incorrect format may not be processed correctly, may
> not be processed promptly, and may get lost.

Comment: Any details regarding what is the 'short time' for the retention?

Comment: According to [this FAQ](https://sendgrid.com/wp-content/uploads/pdf/SendGrid-FAQ-8-18.pdf): "We retain personal data consistent with SendGrid’s then-current data retention policy, which is available  to customers upon request.". I would recommend reaching out to datasubjectrequests@sendgrid.com to find out.